# Copy data in two columns to a single column - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data like below in Excel

[image]

And I want to convert it to

[image]

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($2:2)/2,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($2:2)-1,2))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

With similar formulas, you can map any table to a single column or a single row.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in C1 and drag it down.

```
=INDEX(A:B, (ROW(1:1)-1)/2+1, MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, 2)+1)&""
```

[image]

Comment: index is better than offset. *(+1)*

Answer (score 0):

## OFFSET, ROW, INT & MOD

### Formula

> ```
> =OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/2),MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,2))
> ```

---

### Possibilities for This Row Offset

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/2),MOD(INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/2),2))
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/2),MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,2))
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/2),MOD(INT((ROWS($1:1))/2),2))
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/2),MOD(INT((ROWS($1:1)+2)/2),2))
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/2),MOD(ROWS($1:1),2))
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/2),MOD(INT((ROWS($1:1)+1)/2),2))
```

[image]